# axlsx_rails gem: Columns width issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I'm using axlsx_rails gem to write in .xlsx file. I have multiple columns in spreadsheet based on form fields. It can vary.

I would like to set the column width for all the columns based on data available.

I have used:

```
col_widths= [10,20,30,40,50] 
p = Axlsx::Package.new 
p.use_autowidth = true
wb = p.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(:name => 'try') do |sheet|
sheet.add_row ["hi","hello","how","are","you"]
sheet.column_widths col_widths   ##this column widths method doesn't take an array.
```

Is is possible to pass an array to column_widths method or any other ways to convert col_widths array values to so that we can pass it to column_widths method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx%2FWorksheet%3Acolumn_widths) takes a *list* of column widths, not an *array*.

You can use the [splat operator](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-splat-array-manipulation-destructuring/) to convert your array into a list. Simply add a `*` character:

```
col_widths= [10,20,30,40,50] 
p = Axlsx::Package.new 
p.use_autowidth = true
wb = p.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(:name => 'try') do |sheet|
sheet.add_row ["hi","hello","how","are","you"]
sheet.column_widths *col_widths ## Here I have used the splat operator
```